# Any good ways to obtain zero local means in audio signals?

Tags: matlab, audio, convolution, window-functions, audio-processing

I have asked this question on DSP.SE before, but my question has got no attention. Maybe it was not so related to signal processing.

I needed to divide a discrete audio signal into segments to have some statistical processing and analysis on them. Therefore, segments with fixed local mean would be very helpful for my case. Length of segments are predefined, e.g. **512** samples.

I have tried several things. I do use `reshape()` function to divide audio signal into segments, and then calculate means of every segment as:

```
L = 512;                                % Length of segment
N = floor(length(audio(:,1))/L);        % Number of segments
seg = reshape(audio(1:N*L,1), L, N);    % Reshape into LxN sized matrix
x = mean(seg);                          % Calculate mean of each column
```

Subtracting `x(k)` from each `seg(:,k)` would make each local mean zero, yet it would distort audio signal a lot when segments are joined back.

So, since mean of hanning window is almost **0.5**, substracting `2*x(k)*hann(L)` from each `seg(:,k)` was the first thing I tried. But this time multiplying by **2** *(to make the mean of hanning window be almost equal to **1**)* distorted the neighborhood of midpoints in each segments itself.

[image]

Then, I have used convolution by a smaller hanning window instead of multiplying directly, and subtracting these *(as shown in figure below)* from each `seg(:,k)`.

[image]

This last step gives better results, yet it is still not very useful when segments are smaller. I have seen many amazing approaches here on this site for different problems. So I just wonder if there is any clever ways or existing methods to obtain zero local means which distorts an audio signal less. I read that, this property is useful in some decompositions such as [EMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Huang_transform#Empirical_Mode_Decomposition_.28EMD.29). So maybe I need such decompositions?

Comment: Perhaps you should subtract the local mean, process and then add the local mean back on again before joining the segments back together.  You could also try overlapping your segments (e.g. by 50%) and fading from one segment to another when you rejoin them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a moving average filter:

```
x = cumsum(rand(15*512, 1)-0.5); % generate a random input signal
mean_filter = 1/512 * ones(1, 512); % generate a mean filter
mean = filtfilt(mean_filter, 1, x); % filtfilt is used instead of filter to obtain a symmetric moving average. 

% plot the result
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x);
hold on
plot(mean);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x - mean);
```

You can tune the filter by changing the interval of the mean filter. Using a smaller interval, results in lower means inside each interval, but filters also more low frequencies out of your signal.

[image]

Comment: I added a tuning option, I don't know if it is appropriate for you. Good luck.

Comment: You can also try to use this method first and afterwards the method described in your question. This will probably give less distortion than applying your method directly.